# How to identify/address Excel cell color when cells have been highlighted using conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have an Excel sheet in which many cells have been highlighted using built-in conditional formatting commands. If I try to change the cell color or fill by traditional means, I can neither change the non-filled cells to being filled, nor can I change the filled cells to being non-filled (the sheet is not locked, it's just that changing the color using these has no effect). I can turn a filled cell "blank" by removing conditional formatting from the cell. Basically, I am trying to scan through the entire sheet and check each cell for whether or not it is colored, but I don't know the cell property to address for this particular case of formatting. I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Which part of your question is about writing code?? General software usage questions go to Superuser.com. If you ARE trying to write code, post what you have so far.

Comment: To check for conditional formatting color you may have to use `Cells(x,y).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` or `.ColorIndex` to retrieve the color fill attribute

Comment: @Kubie thanks so much! That worked. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Kubie can you please put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ti7 sure, no problem

Answer (score 1):

To check for conditional formatting color you may have to use

`Cells(x,y).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` or `.ColorIndex`

to retrieve the color fill attribute as `DisplayFormat` compensates for the conditional formatting.